# Performance of <script> Vs eval()

Tags: javascript, performance

I am working on quite a large SPA. The minified javascript code comes more than 1MB. There is quite a complex caching mechanism to reduce the amount of downloads a user has to make, but at a basic level, it works like this:

When a user visits the site for the first time, the javascript is downloaded and saved to the browser local storage as a string. When a user returns at a later time, the string is retrieved from the local storage and evaluated using eval().

My question is this: would it be faster to add a script tag to the DOM, containing the javascript string? Or is eval() faster? Or is there really no difference?

I have tried both and using a script tag seems to be faster, but since we are dealing with times that are of the order of 100ms, I cant really say for sure just by watching it load.

Is there a definitive answer on which method is faster? Or if not, what would be the best way to measure it? I have tried calling console.time() before i evaluate the script and calling console.timeEnd() in the last line of the javascript string. Is this the best approach? the script tag approach seemed to be faster here too, but I am not sure if this is a valid test or not.

Comment: As  it is a large application use of eval is bad idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Why not just use sane HTTP caching headers and let the browser do the work it is supposed to do? Don't write your own caching mechanism utilising `localStorage`!

Comment: Are you `document.write`ing the script or using DOM methods? In any case, `eval` is much more simple and has more consistent cross-browser behaviour. I'd prefer it over the script tag approach.

Comment: Storing js file in localStorage is a bad practice. If user had visited your site and you deploy, changes will not reflect. I would suggest to split your js in modules and load these modules dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but the use of local storage or not, is a topic for another debate. The question is, once we have the script as a string, whats the fastest way to get it running?

Comment: @zan thanks for the link. I had actually read that post before. I figured that because the string we are calling eval() on is already minified, we wont suffer the performance problems they mention. Thoughts?

Comment: @Keith: There should not be any difference. I'd guess `eval` is faster, as it doesn't involve the DOM, but the difference should be negligible. In any case, this decision will not have any effect on page loading speed.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi yeah. Perhaps there is little to be gained here. The page itself is pretty much empty so it loads fast. But because its a SPA, the user cant do anything until the script is evaluated, which on low powered devices seems to take up to 2 seconds. So maybe the answer is: they are the same?